# How to get a chronological list of records from a DynamoDB stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have several related questions here.

1. [DynamoDB documentation on streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) says:

> A shard might split in response to high levels of write activity on its parent table, so that applications can process records from multiple shards in parallel.

My understanding is that when a shard splits into two child shards, DynamoDB stops writing to parent shard and starts writing to both of the child shards in a round-robin fashion. How, in this case, I can establish the chronological order of records? Do I have to read both child shards and sort records by record sequence number in the application layer? What if second child at some point splits into two grandchild shards? Do I now have to read both child and grandchild shards before getting records in order?

2. The aforementioned documentation says:

> Because shards have a lineage (parent and children), applications must always process a parent shard before it processes a child shard.

If you take a look at the [Low-Level DynamoDB Streams API example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.LowLevel.Walkthrough.CompleteProgram.html) provided in the documentation, under *// Get the shards in the stream* comment you'll notice that the code simply gets all shards for a given stream and then iterates over list of shards without bothering with parent-child relationships.

Does it mean that if I want to get a list of records in a chronological order I have to read *ALL* records from a given stream and then sort them by the record sequence number in the application layer?

3. Is trying to get a chronological record order out of the DynamoDB stream a bad idea at all? Please don't ask me about a concrete problem I am trying to solve. I am theorizing here.

---

UPDATE:

The above questions visited me when I was thinking about processing past 24 hours of stream records. But why would one want to process past 24 hours of the stream data in the first place?

I think that streams are built for real-time table change processing in the first place. And processing stream records real-time by triggering a Lambda function makes more sense.

The only use case for going through the past 24 hours of stream records that comes to my mind is some kind of stream record processing failure recovery (for a failure that was very quickly detected).

Bonus question:

4. Can you think of use cases when you would want to dig through past 24 hours of a DynamoDB stream?